# Set GridFooterItem Control ID

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to dynamically set the Control ID of a Telerik RadGrid GridFooterItem and then access the ID via JavaScript, but it is not showing up client-side.  If I could get this working, it would really help [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26166065/1387518) I had.

If I set the ID of the footer like this:

```
private void rgDetailItems_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    var foot = e.Item as GridFooterItem;
    var r = sender as RadGrid;
    foot["DtlTransAmount"].ID = "lblDtlTransAmount";
    foot["DtlTransAmount"].Text = "Total Amount: $";
    //...
```

This is what's generated client-side, a pure HTML table with styling and the correct text, but no ID set:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="RadGrid RadGrid_Default" 
id="ucP_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl05_rgDetailItems" style="width: 1675px;">
    <table class="rgMasterTable" id="ucP_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl05_rgDetailItems_ctl00" 
    style="width: 100%; table-layout: auto; empty-cells: show;">
        ...
        <tfoot>
            <tr class="rgFooter">
                <td>Total Amount: $</td>
                ...
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        ...
```

Where is my Control ID "lblDtlTransAmount"?  I can see the ID of the RadGrid itself, but not the footer.  Is the footer's ID hidden or inaccessible or am I setting it incorrectly server-side?

Comment: the telerik site has tons of examples have you checked their site..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I always read the docs first. Not helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1cwya7h

Answer (score 0):

Is not really clear what you like to achieve. However, if your attempt is to access the Grid Footer Item to set text/total in it, try this:

```
private void rgDetailItems_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{

if (e.Item is GridFooterItem)
 {
    GridFooterItem footerItem = (GridFooterItem)e.Item;
    footerItem["DtlTransAmount"].Text = "Total Amount: $: " + total.ToString();
 }
}
```

For more and different situation you can refer [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-totals-in-footers.html).

Comment: I'm trying to access the ID via JavaScript - I updated my question.  Thanks for asking for clarification.  The code you provided is almost exactly what I already have in my linked question, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridFooterItem)
    {
        GridFooterItem item = e.Item as GridFooterItem;
        string str = "Total Amount: $" + item["ID"].Text;
        Label literal = new Label();
        literal.Text = str;
        literal.ID = "lblDtlTransAmount";
        item["ID"].Controls.Add(literal);
    }
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<Columns>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" UniqueName="Id" Aggregate="Sum">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
</Columns>
```

Please check below screenshot for reference.
[image]

Let me know if any concern.